# pivot longer by looping over certain columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, stata, tidyr, reshape

I have the following data which belongs to my darts league in wide format

```
structure(list(home_team = c("Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", 
"Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", "Combolar", "Combolar", 
"Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar"), home_player = c("Saygın \"Revolver\" Çakar", 
"Alpcan Mercan", "Sedat \"Y.E.S. Man\" Özel", "Ömer Öner", 
"Baho \"Kerberos\" Gullu", "Tolga \"Kabus\" Bora", "Ken \"MAC\" Macdonald", 
"Cem Canik", "Veli Güneş", "Ayaz Gürkan Akın", "Abidin Şimşek", 
"Şükrü \"Taylan\" Çakmak"), home_player_l1_darts = c(29, 
26, 21, 33, 27, 24, 29, 18, 27, 33, 30, 21), home_player_l1_remaining = c(0, 
60, 106, 16, 0, 55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 104), home_player_l2_darts = c(24, 
21, 24, 33, 26, 21, 18, 21, 21, 27, 27, 23), home_player_l2_remaining = c(71, 
157, 97, 2, 0, 110, 68, 0, 25, 40, 15, 0), home_player_l3_darts = c(33, 
33, 31, 25, 30, 25, 18, 23, 21, 24, 21, 25), home_player_l3_remaining = c(0, 
32, 0, 0, 226, 0, 227, 0, 0, 113, 0, 0), home_player_l4_darts = c(33, 
NA, 24, 24, 28, 24, 30, NA, 33, 30, 24, 23), home_player_l4_remaining = c(10, 
NA, 74, 0, 0, 131, 5, NA, 32, 18, 144, 0), home_player_l5_darts = c(30, 
NA, NA, 27, NA, NA, NA, NA, 24, NA, NA, NA), home_player_l5_remaining = c(40, 
NA, NA, 76, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA), home_score = c(2, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3), away_score = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 
1, 3, 3, 0, 2, 3, 3, 1), away_team = c("EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", 
"EYT", "EYT", "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", 
"Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi"), away_player = c("Şenol Dilbaz", 
"Yavuz \"Speedy\" Çay", "Erdem \"The White\" Bakar", "Cem Başak", 
"Ömer Kaçar", "Hanifi \"Zeus\" Kaçar", "Elbruz \"Yetersiz\" Hanaşoğlu", 
"Mevlüt \"Doktor\" Bozdemir", "Mert \"The Bear\" Koçak", "Kanat Özenç", 
"Yener Koçak", "Eray Gürdoğan"), away_player_l1_darts = c(27, 
25, 24, 34, 27, 27, 30, 15, 27, 30, 27, 23), away_player_l1_remaining = c(89, 
0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 10, 318, 2, 33, 0, 0), away_player_l2_darts = c(27, 
22, 24, 32, 24, 19, 17, 21, 21, 29, 30, 21), away_player_l2_remaining = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 173, 0, 0, 83, 0, 0, 0, 68), away_player_l3_darts = c(30, 
32, 33, 27, 33, 27, 21, 21, 21, 23, 18, 27), away_player_l3_remaining = c(32, 
0, 20, 195, 0, 39, 0, 150, 14, 0, 165, 4), away_player_l4_darts = c(36, 
NA, 23, 21, 27, 24, 28, NA, 33, 33, 24, 21), away_player_l4_remaining = c(0, 
NA, 0, 144, 101, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 83), away_player_l5_darts = c(30, 
NA, NA, 27, NA, NA, NA, NA, 24, NA, NA, NA), away_player_l5_remaining = c(0, 
NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 231, NA, NA, NA), home_player_l1_average = c(17.28, 
16.96, 18.81, 14.7, 18.56, 18.58, 17.28, 27.83, 18.56, 15.18, 
14.03, 18.9), home_player_l2_average = c(17.92, 16.38, 16.83, 
15.12, 19.27, 18.62, 24.06, 23.86, 22.67, 17.07, 18, 21.78), 
    home_player_l3_average = c(15.18, 14.21, 16.16, 20.04, 9.17, 
    20.04, 15.22, 21.78, 23.86, 16.17, 23.86, 20.04), home_player_l4_average = c(14.88, 
    NA, 17.79, 20.88, 17.89, 15.42, 16.53, NA, 14.21, 16.1, 14.88, 
    21.78), home_player_l5_average = c(15.37, NA, NA, 15.74, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.88, NA, NA, NA), away_player_l1_average = c(15.26, 
    20.04, 20.88, 14.74, 18.11, 18.56, 16.37, 12.2, 18.48, 15.6, 
    18.56, 21.78), away_player_l2_average = c(18.56, 22.77, 20.88, 
    15.66, 13.67, 26.37, 29.47, 19.9, 23.86, 17.28, 16.7, 20.62
    ), away_player_l3_average = c(15.63, 15.66, 14.58, 11.33, 
    15.18, 17.11, 23.86, 16.71, 23.19, 21.78, 18.67, 18.41), 
    away_player_l4_average = c(13.92, NA, 21.78, 17, 14.81, 20.88, 
    17.89, NA, 15.18, 15.18, 20.88, 19.9), away_player_l5_average = c(16.7, 
    NA, NA, 18.56, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11.25, NA, NA, NA), home_player_average = c(16.12, 
    15.85, 17.4, 17.29, 16.22, 18.16, 18.27, 24.49, 20.03, 16.13, 
    17.69, 20.63), away_player_average = c(16.01, 19.49, 19.53, 
    15.46, 15.44, 20.73, 21.9, 16.27, 18.39, 17.46, 18.7, 20.18
    ), home_win = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), away_win = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), l1_gap = c(-89, 60, 106, 
    16, -12, 55, -10, -318, -2, -33, 80, 104), l2_gap = c(71, 
    157, 97, 2, -173, 110, 68, -83, 25, 40, 15, -68), l3_gap = c(-32, 
    32, -20, -195, 226, -39, 227, -150, -14, 113, -165, -4), 
    l4_gap = c(10, NA, 74, -144, -101, 131, 5, NA, 32, 18, 144, 
    -83), l5_gap = c(40, NA, NA, 76, NA, NA, NA, NA, -231, NA, 
    NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want to pivot the data so that I can see a head to head structure for every match that consists of a maximum of five legs showing the averages and remaning points for each player for each leg

the final data should look like something like this.

```
structure(list(match = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12), 
    leg = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), p1_team = c("Art of Dart", 
    "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", 
    "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", 
    "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", 
    "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", 
    "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", 
    "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", "Art of Dart", 
    "Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar", 
    "Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar", 
    "Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar", 
    "Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar", 
    "Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar", "Combolar"), p1 = c("Saygın \"Revolver\" Çakar", 
    "Saygın \"Revolver\" Çakar", "Saygın \"Revolver\" Çakar", 
    "Saygın \"Revolver\" Çakar", "Saygın \"Revolver\" Çakar", 
    "Alpcan Mercan", "Alpcan Mercan", "Alpcan Mercan", "Sedat \"Y.E.S. Man\" Özel", 
    "Sedat \"Y.E.S. Man\" Özel", "Sedat \"Y.E.S. Man\" Özel", 
    "Sedat \"Y.E.S. Man\" Özel", "Ömer Öner", "Ömer Öner", 
    "Ömer Öner", "Ömer Öner", "Ömer Öner", "Baho \"Kerberos\" Gullu", 
    "Baho \"Kerberos\" Gullu", "Baho \"Kerberos\" Gullu", "Baho \"Kerberos\" Gullu", 
    "Tolga \"Kabus\" Bora", "Tolga \"Kabus\" Bora", "Tolga \"Kabus\" Bora", 
    "Tolga \"Kabus\" Bora", "Ken \"MAC\" Macdonald", "Ken \"MAC\" Macdonald", 
    "Ken \"MAC\" Macdonald", "Ken \"MAC\" Macdonald", "Cem Canik", 
    "Cem Canik", "Cem Canik", "Veli Güneş", "Veli Güneş", 
    "Veli Güneş", "Veli Güneş", "Veli Güneş", "Ayaz Gürkan Akın", 
    "Ayaz Gürkan Akın", "Ayaz Gürkan Akın", "Ayaz Gürkan Akın", 
    "Abidin Şimşek", "Abidin Şimşek", "Abidin Şimşek", 
    "Abidin Şimşek", "Şükrü \"Taylan\" Çakmak", "Şükrü \"Taylan\" Çakmak", 
    "Şükrü \"Taylan\" Çakmak", "Şükrü \"Taylan\" Çakmak"
    ), p1_darts_l = c(29, 24, 33, 33, 30, 26, 21, 33, 21, 24, 
    31, 24, 33, 33, 25, 24, 27, 27, 26, 30, 28, 24, 21, 25, 24, 
    29, 18, 18, 30, 18, 21, 23, 27, 21, 21, 33, 24, 33, 27, 24, 
    30, 30, 27, 21, 24, 21, 23, 25, 23), p1_remaining_l = c(0, 
    71, 0, 10, 40, 60, 157, 32, 106, 97, 0, 74, 16, 2, 0, 0, 
    76, 0, 0, 226, 0, 55, 110, 0, 131, 0, 68, 227, 5, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 25, 0, 32, 0, 0, 40, 113, 18, 80, 15, 0, 144, 104, 0, 
    0, 0), p1_score = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3), p2_score = c(3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1), p2_team = c("EYT", "EYT", 
    "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", 
    "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", 
    "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "EYT", "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", 
    "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", 
    "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", 
    "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", 
    "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", 
    "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi", 
    "Tost Makinesi", "Tost Makinesi"), p2 = c("Şenol Dilbaz", 
    "Şenol Dilbaz", "Şenol Dilbaz", "Şenol Dilbaz", "Şenol Dilbaz", 
    "Yavuz \"Speedy\" Çay", "Yavuz \"Speedy\" Çay", "Yavuz \"Speedy\" Çay", 
    "Erdem \"The White\" Bakar", "Erdem \"The White\" Bakar", 
    "Erdem \"The White\" Bakar", "Erdem \"The White\" Bakar", 
    "Cem Başak", "Cem Başak", "Cem Başak", "Cem Başak", "Cem Başak", 
    "Ömer Kaçar", "Ömer Kaçar", "Ömer Kaçar", "Ömer Kaçar", 
    "Hanifi \"Zeus\" Kaçar", "Hanifi \"Zeus\" Kaçar", "Hanifi \"Zeus\" Kaçar", 
    "Hanifi \"Zeus\" Kaçar", "Elbruz \"Yetersiz\" Hanaşoğlu", 
    "Elbruz \"Yetersiz\" Hanaşoğlu", "Elbruz \"Yetersiz\" Hanaşoğlu", 
    "Elbruz \"Yetersiz\" Hanaşoğlu", "Mevlüt \"Doktor\" Bozdemir", 
    "Mevlüt \"Doktor\" Bozdemir", "Mevlüt \"Doktor\" Bozdemir", 
    "Mert \"The Bear\" Koçak", "Mert \"The Bear\" Koçak", "Mert \"The Bear\" Koçak", 
    "Mert \"The Bear\" Koçak", "Mert \"The Bear\" Koçak", "Kanat Özenç", 
    "Kanat Özenç", "Kanat Özenç", "Kanat Özenç", "Yener Koçak", 
    "Yener Koçak", "Yener Koçak", "Yener Koçak", "Eray Gürdoğan", 
    "Eray Gürdoğan", "Eray Gürdoğan", "Eray Gürdoğan"), 
    p2_darts_l = c(27, 27, 30, 36, 30, 25, 22, 32, 24, 24, 33, 
    23, 34, 32, 27, 21, 27, 27, 24, 33, 27, 27, 19, 27, 24, 30, 
    17, 21, 28, 15, 21, 21, 27, 21, 21, 33, 24, 30, 29, 23, 33, 
    27, 30, 18, 24, 23, 21, 27, 21), p2_remaining_l = c(89, 0, 
    32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 195, 144, 0, 12, 173, 
    0, 101, 0, 0, 39, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 318, 83, 150, 2, 0, 14, 
    0, 231, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 165, 0, 0, 68, 4, 83), p1_average_l = c(17.28, 
    17.92, 15.18, 14.88, 15.37, 16.96, 16.38, 14.21, 18.81, 16.83, 
    16.16, 17.79, 14.7, 15.12, 20.04, 20.88, 15.74, 18.56, 19.27, 
    9.17, 17.89, 18.58, 18.62, 20.04, 15.42, 17.28, 24.06, 15.22, 
    16.53, 27.83, 23.86, 21.78, 18.56, 22.67, 23.86, 14.21, 20.88, 
    15.18, 17.07, 16.17, 16.1, 14.03, 18, 23.86, 14.88, 18.9, 
    21.78, 20.04, 21.78), p2_average_l = c(15.26, 18.56, 15.63, 
    13.92, 16.7, 20.04, 22.77, 15.66, 20.88, 20.88, 14.58, 21.78, 
    14.74, 15.66, 11.33, 17, 18.56, 18.11, 13.67, 15.18, 14.81, 
    18.56, 26.37, 17.11, 20.88, 16.37, 29.47, 23.86, 17.89, 12.2, 
    19.9, 16.71, 18.48, 23.86, 23.19, 15.18, 11.25, 15.6, 17.28, 
    21.78, 15.18, 18.56, 16.7, 18.67, 20.88, 21.78, 20.62, 18.41, 
    19.9), p1_average = c(16.12, 16.12, 16.12, 16.12, 16.12, 
    15.85, 15.85, 15.85, 17.4, 17.4, 17.4, 17.4, 17.29, 17.29, 
    17.29, 17.29, 17.29, 16.22, 16.22, 16.22, 16.22, 18.16, 18.16, 
    18.16, 18.16, 18.27, 18.27, 18.27, 18.27, 24.49, 24.49, 24.49, 
    20.03, 20.03, 20.03, 20.03, 20.03, 16.13, 16.13, 16.13, 16.13, 
    17.69, 17.69, 17.69, 17.69, 20.63, 20.63, 20.63, 20.63), 
    p2_average = c(16.01, 16.01, 16.01, 16.01, 16.01, 19.49, 
    19.49, 19.49, 19.53, 19.53, 19.53, 19.53, 15.46, 15.46, 15.46, 
    15.46, 15.46, 15.44, 15.44, 15.44, 15.44, 20.73, 20.73, 20.73, 
    20.73, 21.9, 21.9, 21.9, 21.9, 16.27, 16.27, 16.27, 18.39, 
    18.39, 18.39, 18.39, 18.39, 17.46, 17.46, 17.46, 17.46, 18.7, 
    18.7, 18.7, 18.7, 20.18, 20.18, 20.18, 20.18), p1_win = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), p2_win = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), gap_l = c(-89, 71, -32, 10, 40, 60, 157, 
    32, 106, 97, -20, 74, 16, 2, -195, -144, 76, -12, -173, 226, 
    -101, 55, 110, -39, 131, -10, 68, 227, 5, -318, -83, -150, 
    -2, 25, -14, 32, -231, -33, 40, 113, 18, 80, 15, -165, 144, 
    104, -68, -4, -83)), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This was done by the following Stata code

```
rename home_player* p1*
rename away_player* p2*
forval i=1/5{
rename *_l`i'_* *_*_l`i'
rename l`i'_* *_l`i'
}
rename home_* p1_*
rename away_* p2_*

gen match=_n
reshape long p1_darts_l p1_remaining_l p2_darts_l p2_remaining_l p1_average_l p2_average_l gap_l, i(match) j(leg)
drop if missing(p1_darts_l)
export 

drop *score

gen performance1=p1_average-p1_average_l
gen performance2=p2_average-p2_average_l
gen performance_dif12=p1_average-p2_average
logit p1_win performance1 performance2 performance_dif12
```

I want to reproduce this using the tidyverse, any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance...

I have tried multiple AI solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach to achieve your desired result which first does some renaming to get consistent column names then uses `tidyr::pivot_longer` for the reshaping and finally again does some renaming (home -> p1, ...) and cleaning to get rid of the NAs:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

dat |>
  tibble::rowid_to_column(var = "match") |> 
  rename(
    home_player_average1 = home_player_average,
    away_player_average1 = away_player_average) |> 
  rename_with(
    ~ gsub("^(.*?)_(l\\d+)_(.*)$", "\\2_\\1_\\3", .x),
    matches("^.*_l\\d")
  ) |>
  pivot_longer(matches("^l\\d"),
    names_to = c("leg", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "^(\\d+)_(.*)$",
    names_prefix = "l"
  ) |> 
  # Final cleaning and renaming
  select(match, leg, everything()) |> 
  rename_with(
    ~ gsub("^home", "p1", .x), starts_with("home")  
  ) |> 
  rename_with(
    ~ gsub("^away", "p2", .x), starts_with("away")  
  ) |> 
  filter(!is.na(gap))
#> # A tibble: 49 × 19
#>    match leg   p1_team     p1_player         p1_score p2_score p2_team p2_player
#>    <int> <chr> <chr>       <chr>                <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>    
#>  1     1 1     Art of Dart "Saygın \"Revolv…        2        3 EYT     "Şenol D…
#>  2     1 2     Art of Dart "Saygın \"Revolv…        2        3 EYT     "Şenol D…
#>  3     1 3     Art of Dart "Saygın \"Revolv…        2        3 EYT     "Şenol D…
#>  4     1 4     Art of Dart "Saygın \"Revolv…        2        3 EYT     "Şenol D…
#>  5     1 5     Art of Dart "Saygın \"Revolv…        2        3 EYT     "Şenol D…
#>  6     2 1     Art of Dart "Alpcan Mercan"          0        3 EYT     "Yavuz \…
#>  7     2 2     Art of Dart "Alpcan Mercan"          0        3 EYT     "Yavuz \…
#>  8     2 3     Art of Dart "Alpcan Mercan"          0        3 EYT     "Yavuz \…
#>  9     3 1     Art of Dart "Sedat \"Y.E.S. …        1        3 EYT     "Erdem \…
#> 10     3 2     Art of Dart "Sedat \"Y.E.S. …        1        3 EYT     "Erdem \…
#> # ℹ 39 more rows
#> # ℹ 11 more variables: p1_player_average1 <dbl>, p2_player_average1 <dbl>,
#> #   p1_win <dbl>, p2_win <dbl>, p1_player_darts <dbl>,
#> #   p1_player_remaining <dbl>, p2_player_darts <dbl>,
#> #   p2_player_remaining <dbl>, p1_player_average <dbl>,
#> #   p2_player_average <dbl>, gap <dbl>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also a `reshape` in R which works similar to that of Stata.

You could, first, put the times (numbers) at the end of the variables, while removing the "l" and replacing the "_" by ".".

```
> names(dat) <- gsub(r"{(.*)?(l)(\d)(_)(.*)}", '\\1\\5.\\3', names(dat))
```

Looks like this:

```
> names(dat)
 [1] "home_team"               "home_player"            
 [3] "home_player_darts.1"     "home_player_remaining.1"
 [5] "home_player_darts.2"     "home_player_remaining.2"
 [7] "home_player_darts.3"     "home_player_remaining.3"
 [9] "home_player_darts.4"     "home_player_remaining.4"
[11] "home_player_darts.5"     "home_player_remaining.5"
[13] "home_score"              "away_score"             
[15] "away_team"               "away_player"            
[17] "away_player_darts.1"     "away_player_remaining.1"
[19] "away_player_darts.2"     "away_player_remaining.2"
[21] "away_player_darts.3"     "away_player_remaining.3"
[23] "away_player_darts.4"     "away_player_remaining.4"
[25] "away_player_darts.5"     "away_player_remaining.5"
[27] "home_player_average.1"   "home_player_average.2"  
[29] "home_player_average.3"   "home_player_average.4"  
[31] "home_player_average.5"   "away_player_average.1"  
[33] "away_player_average.2"   "away_player_average.3"  
[35] "away_player_average.4"   "away_player_average.5"  
[37] "home_player_average"     "away_player_average"    
[39] "home_win"                "away_win"               
[41] "gap.1"                   "gap.2"                  
[43] "gap.3"                   "gap.4"                  
[45] "gap.5"
```

Now `reshape` can automatically recognize times and you can reshape without much effort.

```
> reshape(dat, varying=grep('\\d$', names(dat)), direction='long')
       home_team             home_player home_score away_score     away_team
1.1  Art of Dart Saygın "Revolver" Çakar          2          3           EYT
2.1  Art of Dart           Alpcan Mercan          0          3           EYT
3.1  Art of Dart Sedat "Y.E.S. Man" Özel          1          3           EYT
4.1  Art of Dart               Ömer Öner          2          3           EYT
5.1  Art of Dart   Baho "Kerberos" Gullu          3          1           EYT
6.1  Art of Dart      Tolga "Kabus" Bora          1          3           EYT
7.1     Combolar     Ken "MAC" Macdonald          1          3 Tost Makinesi
8.1     Combolar               Cem Canik          3          0 Tost Makinesi
9.1     Combolar              Veli Güneş          3          2 Tost Makinesi
10.1    Combolar        Ayaz Gürkan Akın          1          3 Tost Makinesi
11.1    Combolar           Abidin Şimşek          1          3 Tost Makinesi
12.1    Combolar   Şükrü "Taylan" Çakmak          3          1 Tost Makinesi
1.2  Art of Dart Saygın "Revolver" Çakar          2          3           EYT
2.2  Art of Dart           Alpcan Mercan          0          3           EYT
3.2  Art of Dart Sedat "Y.E.S. Man" Özel          1          3           EYT
4.2  Art of Dart               Ömer Öner          2          3           EYT
5.2  Art of Dart   Baho "Kerberos" Gullu          3          1           EYT
6.2  Art of Dart      Tolga "Kabus" Bora          1          3           EYT
7.2     Combolar     Ken "MAC" Macdonald          1          3 Tost Makinesi
8.2     Combolar               Cem Canik          3          0 Tost Makinesi
9.2     Combolar              Veli Güneş          3          2 Tost Makinesi
10.2    Combolar        Ayaz Gürkan Akın          1          3 Tost Makinesi
11.2    Combolar           Abidin Şimşek          1          3 Tost Makinesi
12.2    Combolar   Şükrü "Taylan" Çakmak          3          1 Tost Makinesi
1.3  Art of Dart Saygın "Revolver" Çakar          2          3           EYT
2.3  Art of Dart           Alpcan Mercan          0          3           EYT
3.3  Art of Dart Sedat "Y.E.S. Man" Özel          1          3           EYT
4.3  Art of Dart               Ömer Öner          2          3           EYT
5.3  Art of Dart   Baho "Kerberos" Gullu          3          1           EYT
6.3  Art of Dart      Tolga "Kabus" Bora          1          3           EYT
7.3     Combolar     Ken "MAC" Macdonald          1          3 Tost Makinesi
8.3     Combolar               Cem Canik          3          0 Tost Makinesi
9.3     Combolar              Veli Güneş          3          2 Tost Makinesi
10.3    Combolar        Ayaz Gürkan Akın          1          3 Tost Makinesi
11.3    Combolar           Abidin Şimşek          1          3 Tost Makinesi
12.3    Combolar   Şükrü "Taylan" Çakmak          3          1 Tost Makinesi
1.4  Art of Dart Saygın "Revolver" Çakar          2          3           EYT
2.4  Art of Dart           Alpcan Mercan          0          3           EYT
3.4  Art of Dart Sedat "Y.E.S. Man" Özel          1          3           EYT
4.4  Art of Dart               Ömer Öner          2          3           EYT
5.4  Art of Dart   Baho "Kerberos" Gullu          3          1           EYT
6.4  Art of Dart      Tolga "Kabus" Bora          1          3           EYT
7.4     Combolar     Ken "MAC" Macdonald          1          3 Tost Makinesi
8.4     Combolar               Cem Canik          3          0 Tost Makinesi
9.4     Combolar              Veli Güneş          3          2 Tost Makinesi
10.4    Combolar        Ayaz Gürkan Akın          1          3 Tost Makinesi
11.4    Combolar           Abidin Şimşek          1          3 Tost Makinesi
12.4    Combolar   Şükrü "Taylan" Çakmak          3          1 Tost Makinesi
1.5  Art of Dart Saygın "Revolver" Çakar          2          3           EYT
2.5  Art of Dart           Alpcan Mercan          0          3           EYT
3.5  Art of Dart Sedat "Y.E.S. Man" Özel          1          3           EYT
4.5  Art of Dart               Ömer Öner          2          3           EYT
5.5  Art of Dart   Baho "Kerberos" Gullu          3          1           EYT
6.5  Art of Dart      Tolga "Kabus" Bora          1          3           EYT
7.5     Combolar     Ken "MAC" Macdonald          1          3 Tost Makinesi
8.5     Combolar               Cem Canik          3          0 Tost Makinesi
9.5     Combolar              Veli Güneş          3          2 Tost Makinesi
10.5    Combolar        Ayaz Gürkan Akın          1          3 Tost Makinesi
11.5    Combolar           Abidin Şimşek          1          3 Tost Makinesi
12.5    Combolar   Şükrü "Taylan" Çakmak          3          1 Tost Makinesi
                     away_player home_player_average away_player_average
1.1                 Şenol Dilbaz               17.28               15.26
2.1           Yavuz "Speedy" Çay               16.96               20.04
3.1      Erdem "The White" Bakar               18.81               20.88
4.1                    Cem Başak               14.70               14.74
5.1                   Ömer Kaçar               18.56               18.11
6.1          Hanifi "Zeus" Kaçar               18.58               18.56
7.1  Elbruz "Yetersiz" Hanaşoğlu               17.28               16.37
8.1     Mevlüt "Doktor" Bozdemir               27.83               12.20
9.1        Mert "The Bear" Koçak               18.56               18.48
10.1                 Kanat Özenç               15.18               15.60
11.1                 Yener Koçak               14.03               18.56
12.1               Eray Gürdoğan               18.90               21.78
1.2                 Şenol Dilbaz               17.92               18.56
2.2           Yavuz "Speedy" Çay               16.38               22.77
3.2      Erdem "The White" Bakar               16.83               20.88
4.2                    Cem Başak               15.12               15.66
5.2                   Ömer Kaçar               19.27               13.67
6.2          Hanifi "Zeus" Kaçar               18.62               26.37
7.2  Elbruz "Yetersiz" Hanaşoğlu               24.06               29.47
8.2     Mevlüt "Doktor" Bozdemir               23.86               19.90
9.2        Mert "The Bear" Koçak               22.67               23.86
10.2                 Kanat Özenç               17.07               17.28
11.2                 Yener Koçak               18.00               16.70
12.2               Eray Gürdoğan               21.78               20.62
1.3                 Şenol Dilbaz               15.18               15.63
2.3           Yavuz "Speedy" Çay               14.21               15.66
3.3      Erdem "The White" Bakar               16.16               14.58
4.3                    Cem Başak               20.04               11.33
5.3                   Ömer Kaçar                9.17               15.18
6.3          Hanifi "Zeus" Kaçar               20.04               17.11
7.3  Elbruz "Yetersiz" Hanaşoğlu               15.22               23.86
8.3     Mevlüt "Doktor" Bozdemir               21.78               16.71
9.3        Mert "The Bear" Koçak               23.86               23.19
10.3                 Kanat Özenç               16.17               21.78
11.3                 Yener Koçak               23.86               18.67
12.3               Eray Gürdoğan               20.04               18.41
1.4                 Şenol Dilbaz               14.88               13.92
2.4           Yavuz "Speedy" Çay                  NA                  NA
3.4      Erdem "The White" Bakar               17.79               21.78
4.4                    Cem Başak               20.88               17.00
5.4                   Ömer Kaçar               17.89               14.81
6.4          Hanifi "Zeus" Kaçar               15.42               20.88
7.4  Elbruz "Yetersiz" Hanaşoğlu               16.53               17.89
8.4     Mevlüt "Doktor" Bozdemir                  NA                  NA
9.4        Mert "The Bear" Koçak               14.21               15.18
10.4                 Kanat Özenç               16.10               15.18
11.4                 Yener Koçak               14.88               20.88
12.4               Eray Gürdoğan               21.78               19.90
1.5                 Şenol Dilbaz               15.37               16.70
2.5           Yavuz "Speedy" Çay                  NA                  NA
3.5      Erdem "The White" Bakar                  NA                  NA
4.5                    Cem Başak               15.74               18.56
5.5                   Ömer Kaçar                  NA                  NA
6.5          Hanifi "Zeus" Kaçar                  NA                  NA
7.5  Elbruz "Yetersiz" Hanaşoğlu                  NA                  NA
8.5     Mevlüt "Doktor" Bozdemir                  NA                  NA
9.5        Mert "The Bear" Koçak               20.88               11.25
10.5                 Kanat Özenç                  NA                  NA
11.5                 Yener Koçak                  NA                  NA
12.5               Eray Gürdoğan                  NA                  NA
     home_win away_win time home_player_darts home_player_remaining
1.1         0        1    1                29                     0
2.1         0        1    1                26                    60
3.1         0        1    1                21                   106
4.1         0        1    1                33                    16
5.1         1        0    1                27                     0
6.1         0        1    1                24                    55
7.1         0        1    1                29                     0
8.1         1        0    1                18                     0
9.1         1        0    1                27                     0
10.1        0        1    1                33                     0
11.1        0        1    1                30                    80
12.1        1        0    1                21                   104
1.2         0        1    2                24                    71
2.2         0        1    2                21                   157
3.2         0        1    2                24                    97
4.2         0        1    2                33                     2
5.2         1        0    2                26                     0
6.2         0        1    2                21                   110
7.2         0        1    2                18                    68
8.2         1        0    2                21                     0
9.2         1        0    2                21                    25
10.2        0        1    2                27                    40
11.2        0        1    2                27                    15
12.2        1        0    2                23                     0
1.3         0        1    3                33                     0
2.3         0        1    3                33                    32
3.3         0        1    3                31                     0
4.3         0        1    3                25                     0
5.3         1        0    3                30                   226
6.3         0        1    3                25                     0
7.3         0        1    3                18                   227
8.3         1        0    3                23                     0
9.3         1        0    3                21                     0
10.3        0        1    3                24                   113
11.3        0        1    3                21                     0
12.3        1        0    3                25                     0
1.4         0        1    4                33                    10
2.4         0        1    4                NA                    NA
3.4         0        1    4                24                    74
4.4         0        1    4                24                     0
5.4         1        0    4                28                     0
6.4         0        1    4                24                   131
7.4         0        1    4                30                     5
8.4         1        0    4                NA                    NA
9.4         1        0    4                33                    32
10.4        0        1    4                30                    18
11.4        0        1    4                24                   144
12.4        1        0    4                23                     0
1.5         0        1    5                30                    40
2.5         0        1    5                NA                    NA
3.5         0        1    5                NA                    NA
4.5         0        1    5                27                    76
5.5         1        0    5                NA                    NA
6.5         0        1    5                NA                    NA
7.5         0        1    5                NA                    NA
8.5         1        0    5                NA                    NA
9.5         1        0    5                24                     0
10.5        0        1    5                NA                    NA
11.5        0        1    5                NA                    NA
12.5        1        0    5                NA                    NA
     away_player_darts away_player_remaining  gap id
1.1                 27                    89  -89  1
2.1                 25                     0   60  2
3.1                 24                     0  106  3
4.1                 34                     0   16  4
5.1                 27                    12  -12  5
6.1                 27                     0   55  6
7.1                 30                    10  -10  7
8.1                 15                   318 -318  8
9.1                 27                     2   -2  9
10.1                30                    33  -33 10
11.1                27                     0   80 11
12.1                23                     0  104 12
1.2                 27                     0   71  1
2.2                 22                     0  157  2
3.2                 24                     0   97  3
4.2                 32                     0    2  4
5.2                 24                   173 -173  5
6.2                 19                     0  110  6
7.2                 17                     0   68  7
8.2                 21                    83  -83  8
9.2                 21                     0   25  9
10.2                29                     0   40 10
11.2                30                     0   15 11
12.2                21                    68  -68 12
1.3                 30                    32  -32  1
2.3                 32                     0   32  2
3.3                 33                    20  -20  3
4.3                 27                   195 -195  4
5.3                 33                     0  226  5
6.3                 27                    39  -39  6
7.3                 21                     0  227  7
8.3                 21                   150 -150  8
9.3                 21                    14  -14  9
10.3                23                     0  113 10
11.3                18                   165 -165 11
12.3                27                     4   -4 12
1.4                 36                     0   10  1
2.4                 NA                    NA   NA  2
3.4                 23                     0   74  3
4.4                 21                   144 -144  4
5.4                 27                   101 -101  5
6.4                 24                     0  131  6
7.4                 28                     0    5  7
8.4                 NA                    NA   NA  8
9.4                 33                     0   32  9
10.4                33                     0   18 10
11.4                24                     0  144 11
12.4                21                    83  -83 12
1.5                 30                     0   40  1
2.5                 NA                    NA   NA  2
3.5                 NA                    NA   NA  3
4.5                 27                     0   76  4
5.5                 NA                    NA   NA  5
6.5                 NA                    NA   NA  6
7.5                 NA                    NA   NA  7
8.5                 NA                    NA   NA  8
9.5                 24                   231 -231  9
10.5                NA                    NA   NA 10
11.5                NA                    NA   NA 11
12.5                NA                    NA   NA 12
```